# Different coders for the same class in dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to use different coders for the same class for two different scenarios:

1. Reading from JSON input files - using `data = TextIO.Read.from(options.getInput()).withCoder(new Coder1())`
2. Elsewhere in the job I want the class to be persisted using `SerializableCoder` using `data.setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(MyClass.class)`

It works locally, but fails when run in the cloud with

```
 Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B227365.
```

Is it a supported scenario? The reason to do this in the first place is to avoid read/write of JSON format, and on the other hand make reading from input files more efficient (UTF-8 parsing is part of the JSON reader, so it can read from InputStream directly)

Clarifications:
Coder1 is my coder.

The other coder is a  `SerializableCoder.of(MyClass.class)`

How does the system choose which coder to use? The two formats are binary incompatible, and it looks like due to some optimization, the second coder is used for data format which can only be read by the first coder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using two different coders like that should work. (With the caveat that the coder in #2 will only be used if the system choses to persist 'data' instead of optimizing it into surround computations.)

Are you using your own Coders or ones provided by the Dataflow SDK? Quick caveat on TextIO -- because it uses newlines to encode element boundaries, you'll get into trouble if you use a coder that produces encoded values containing something that can be mistaken for a newline. You really should only use textual encodings within TextIO. We're hoping to make that clearer in the future.